# Symfony Form Validation Constraint Expression

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I have form, and need to create inline validation:

```
$builder
        ->add('Count1', 'integer', [
            'data'        => 1,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
                new NotNull(),
            ],
        ])
        ->add('Count2', 'integer', [
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
                new NotNull(),
            ],
        ])
        ->add('Count3', 'integer', [
            'data'        => 0,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
                new NotNull(),
            ],
        ])
```

How white inline validation Expression for rules

1. Count2 >=Count1
2. Count3 <=Count2
3. Count2 >= $someVariable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Other solution by using [Expression Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) for cases 1 and 2.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

// ...

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'constraints' => [
            new Assert\Expression([
                'expression' => 'value["Count2"] >= value["Count1"]',
                'message' => 'count2 must be greater than or equal to count1'
            ]),
            new Assert\Expression([
                'expression' => 'value["Count3"] <= value["Count2"]',
                'message' => 'count3 must be less than or equal to count2'
            ]),
        ],
    ]);
}
```

For case 3 you can use `Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual` constraint directly on `Count2` field.

> I guess your form doesn't have a binding object model, otherwise to read [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) referred is enough and better because you could use these expression on your properties directly.

Comment: I actually like this answer more than mine own =)

Comment: Just a note: from symfony 3 on you should use `configureOptions`.

I'm writing this as `setDefaultOptions` fails silently (as it's just a simple name)

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize `CallbackValidator` ([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)):

In your case, in order to validate one field againt another, you need to add constraint to a form type, not the field:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'constraints' => array(
            new Assert\Callback(function($data){
                // $data is instance of object (or array) with all properties
                // you can compare Count1, Count2 and Count 3 
                // and raise validation errors
            });
        )
    ));
}
```

You can also pass `constraints` option while creating a form if you don't want to set it in `setDefaultOptions`.

Comment: Just a note: from symfony 3 on you should use `configureOptions`.

I'm writing this as `setDefaultOptions` fails silently (as it's just a simple name)

Comment: @DonCallisto very good point. The approach above was first deprecated and then removed altogether...

Comment: Please update your answer with an edit for those version of symfony: it would be great! :)

Answer (score 3):

Starting from easiest

3) Count2 >= $someVariable

```
    ->add('Count3', 'integer', [
        'data'        => 0,
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
            new NotNull(),
            new GreaterThanOrEqual($someVariable),
        ],
    ])
```

1) As for two first, you must implement constraint for a class scope, rather than property scope. And assign these constraints for a whole form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
    ->add('Count1', 'integer', [
        'data'        => 1,
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
            new NotNull(),
        ],
    ])
    ->add('Count2', 'integer', [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
            new NotNull(),
        ],
    ])
    ->add('Count3', 'integer', [
        'data'        => 0,
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
            new NotNull(),
        ],
    ])
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
     $resolver->setDefaults(['constraints' => [
            new YourCustomConstraint(),
          ]]);
}
```

How to implement validator, see in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html).
But in your `YourCustomConstraintValidator` you will have something like

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
     if ($value->getCount1() > $value->getCount2() {
           $this->context->addViolation(...);
     }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: from symfony 3 on you should use `configureOptions`.

I'm writing this as `setDefaultOptions` fails silently (as it's just a simple name)

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem comparing two dates using Symfony's Expressions.

This is the code that works:

```
 $builder->add(
            'end',
            DateTimeType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'Campaign Ends At',
                'data' => $entity->getEnd(),
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $disabled,
                'widget'  => 'single_text',
                'constraints' => [
                    new Assert\GreaterThan(['value' => 'today']),
                    new Assert\Expression(
                                [
                                    //here end and start are the name of two fields
                                    'expression' => 'value > this.getParent()["start"].getData()',
                                    'message' => 'my.form.error.end.date.bigger.than.start'
                                ]
                            ),
                ]

            ]
        );
```