# Symfony4 validate form with mapped false form fields

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have an entity with `age`.
I created a search form to show records where `ageMin` < `age` < `ageMax`.
So I added non mapped form fields `ageMin` and `ageMax`:

```
$builder
    ->add('ageMin', IntegerType::class, [
        'mapped' => false,
        'required' => false
    ])
    ->add('ageMax', IntegerType::class, [
        'mapped' => false,
        'required' => false
    ])
;
```

I would like to check if the user has entered min greater than max (very simple requirement!).

I tried [Symfony validate form with mapped false form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911686/symfony-validate-form-with-mapped-false-form-fields) but it is for symfony 2 and Components required is confusing for me.

I found these help pages too:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html#form-option-constraints and tried:

```
->add('ageMin', IntegerType::class, [
            'mapped' => false, 
            'required' => false,
            'constraints' => new LessThan('ageMax')
        ])
```

There are no errors but it doesn't work.

Other page:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html

Comment: You're passing the string `"ageMax"` to `LessThan` and it can't work like that.

Comment: @cezar : ok, is there a way to reference an other form field in constraints or is it only constant?

Comment: Please check the answer.

Comment: You might also take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40290332/3848833

Answer (score 0):

If there is an entity with the property `age` you could use `LessThan` for `ageMin` and `GreaterThan` for `ageMax` to compare these values to `age`.

```
$builder
    ->add('ageMin', IntegerType::class, [
        'mapped' => false,
        'required' => false,
        'constraints' => [new LessThan(['propertyPath' => 'age'])]
    ])
    ->add('ageMax', IntegerType::class, [
        'mapped' => false,
        'required' => false,
        'constraints' => [new GreaterThan(['propertyPath' => 'age'])]
    ])
;
```

Take care for proper import of the constraints.

EDIT:

The example above assumes that the form makes use of the entity having the property `age`. If the name of the entity class is `Foo`, then the method `configureOptions` would look like:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Foo::class,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: yes I have an entity with `age` but my need is just to check that the user doesn't entered an `ageMin` greater than `ageMax`

Comment: If `ageMin` is less than `age` and `ageMax` is greater than `age`, then `ageMax` is greater than `ageMin`. Both properties are optional, so the users might enter just one of them, and in that case you would be comparing an integer to `null`.  You would have to implement additional logic to catch this edge case. If you follow the approach from my answer, you'll have cleaner code that is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: This also accomplishes exactly the requirement in your question: *"I created a search form to show records where ageMin < age < ageMax."*

Comment: 'constraints' => [new LessThan(['propertyPath' => 'age'])] (based on https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29719)

returns error:

  Invalid property path "age" provided to "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\LessThan" constraint: Neither the property "age" nor one of the methods "getAge()", "age()", "isAge()", "hasAge()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\Form".

Comment: @bcag2 Please check the edit. It is probably because you haven't set up the `configureOptions` in your form class.

Comment: Constraints configured with the `constraints` option of the form are attached to the built form. I suggest that you add the constraints to the underlying class instead. In this case the property should work as expected.

Comment: @xabbuh Thank you very much for your comment. Could you please provide a code example how the `constraints` should be properly added?

Comment: I am not sure that's actually possible.